# Logins in an interval?

Tags: bash, login, last

How can I get who was logged in in an interval? I tried last -t, but it was not what I was looking for.
I want to get who was logged in between 
May 11. 10:00:00 and May 15. 22:00:00 
for example.

Comment: Can we assume that your version of `last` doesn't have the `-s` option (or `--since`)?

Comment: Yes. We can assume.

Answer (score 1):

logs / audits.  Logs are the best.

Please specify your OS.

On Linux, you can use the "audit" system to log all logins.  E.g. this is enabled by default on Fedora.  Entries appear in the system journal.  There is also a dedicated search tool `ausearch`, which uses a log file.  I assume the log is archived periodically (i.e. logrotate); the tool apparently only searches one log file.  Logins are probably the most obvious use for this; it's mentioned as the first example in RHEL documentation.  It says to use `ausearch --message USER_LOGIN`.  Date ranges are also useful; the relevant options are `--start` and `--end`.

On Debian you can install audit, but by default you get logins recorded in `/var/log/auth.log`.  I guess it's mainly implemented by PAM.

At least with Debian, you will probably want some way to distinguish, from noise generated by cron jobs (when cron changes to a specific user for the job).

So as you can see, my first line is as specific as one can be, without answering the second.  Please remember that "Unix & Linux" covers a forest of operating systems released over more than 4 decades, e.g. as in this [33 page diagram](https://www.levenez.com/unix/unix_a4.pdf).